# Where does the determinant rule for eliminating arbitrary constants in a DE come from?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

[image]

I understand the process. Given an equation with two arbitrary constants, the derivative was taken two times. Then all the terms were transposed to the right side. The terms were then put in a 3 by 3 determinant which is equated to zero. Through determinant properties, the common factor for each column is factored out. Basket method can then be used to solve the differential equation.

My question is why is the determinant of the systems of equation equated to zero in obtaining the DE?

Answer (score 2):

If you have 2 independent 3D vectors $u$, $v$, then the subspace spanned by these vectors is solution to $\det(y,u,v)=0$.

- It is a subspace, as this equation is linear in $y$,
- $u$ and $v$ are inside this subspace
- The subspace has the correct dimension.

This also applies pointwise to the functions in the task.